# Robot.createScreenCapture returning black images in Windows 8.1

Tags: java, windows, screenshot

I'm currently trying to write an automation code in java. In order to do that, I capture my screen and loop through it to find something I need to clic.
While working accordingly on my windows XP computer (I do get a correct screen-shot and thus can loop through it),  on my windows 8.1 Machine I only get a black one.
Here is a part of my (faulty?) code.

```
public class NewClass {

    static final Dimension dim_D = new Dimension(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
    static final int i_SCREEN_WIDTH = (int) dim_D.getWidth();
    static final int i_SCREEN_HEIGHT = (int) dim_D.getHeight();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();

            try {
                BufferedImage biCapturedScreen = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(0, 0, i_SCREEN_WIDTH, i_SCREEN_HEIGHT));
                ImageIO.write(biCapturedScreen, "PNG", new File("D:\\tempShot.png"));

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(NewClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        } catch (AWTException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

As I get a PNG 1920x1080 black image, I guess this is not a writing permission problem.
Any idea why this isn't working on my 8.1 machine?
Thanks!
Thomas B.

Comment: What version of Java?  Does it work on other versions of Windows or OSs?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm developing under jdk1.7.0_55 and jre8 is installed in both cases. These are the only two OSs I can try my code on for now.

Comment: Well, it works under Windows 7, Java 7 & 8, so I'm guessing it's an issue with Windows 8.1...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I was afraid this could be the reason why as an issue with my code would have been far much easier to solve... If anyone could try on a 8.1 OS.